# What's the difference between using add().addToBackStack(), add().detach() and replace().addToBackStack() in a FragmentTransaction?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

In FragmentTransaction item on Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html), it is described that the method `replace()` is the same as calling the method `remove()` for all fragments added in the currently view and then called the method `add()`. In this case, to recover the previous fragment, we could use `addBackToStack()`, it means that transaction state is still being managed by the fragment manager and will reverse its operation when we popped off the stack.

In the other hand, when we implement the transaction using `add()`, beyond the use of `add().addBackToStack()`, we can use the `detach()` method and recovering the fragment using `attach()`, which have the same behavior that `addBackToStack()`.

So what is the difference behind the scenes between these scenarios?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I researched more and apparently, the difference between `detach()` and `addToBackStack ()` is in the life cycle of Fragment. When we add the Fragment in the back stack, is called in sequence the methods `onPause()`, `onStop()` and after the `onDestroyView()`. In this state, the fragment clean up the resources associated with its view and "stay" there waiting to be called again. Returning to the layout from the back stack is called the method `onCreateView()` just for the fragment to draw its user interface. Actually, the fragment isn't destroyed.

In the other side, when we use `detach()` to remove or replace the fragment, is called in sequence all same methods cited first (`onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroyView()`) adding this two methods: `onDestroy()`, to do final cleanup of the fragment's state and `onDetach()`, to detach the fragment to being no longer associated with its activity.

Basically, behind the scenes, they don't have the same behavior: using the `addToBackStack()` the fragments remain instantiated and `detach()`, don't.